# Update Counter collection in python with string, not letter

Tags: python, collections, counter

How to update a Counter with a string, not the letters of the string? 
For example, after initializing this counter with two strings:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(['black','blue'])
```

"add" to it another string such as 'red'. When I use the update() method it adds the letters 'r','e','d':

```
c.update('red')
c
>>Counter({'black': 1, 'blue': 1, 'd': 1, 'e': 1, 'r': 1})
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can update it with a dictionary, since add another string is same as update the key with count +1:

```
from collections import Counter
c = Counter(['black','blue'])

c.update({"red": 1})  

c
# Counter({'black': 1, 'blue': 1, 'red': 1})
```

If the key already exists, the count will increase by one:

```
c.update({"red": 1})

c
# Counter({'black': 1, 'blue': 1, 'red': 2})
```

Comment: So there is no c.increment("red") or something of that sort?  This seems a bit heavyhanded for a basic operation although it certainly does work.

Comment: @demongolem c["red"] += 1

Answer (score 29):

```
c.update(['red'])
>>> c
Counter({'black': 1, 'blue': 1, 'red': 1})
```

> Source can be an iterable, a dictionary, or another Counter instance.

Although a string is an iterable, the result is not what you expected.  First convert it to a list, tuple, etc.

Answer (score 18):

You can use:

```
c["red"]+=1
# or
c.update({"red": 1})
# or 
c.update(["red"])
```

All these options will work regardless of the key being present or not. And if present, they will increase the count by 1

Comment: For those that need performance, the first one is the fastest by using %timeit in IPython/Jupyter, including the Counter instantiation

1. 5.77 µs ± 68.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
2. 7.43 µs ± 35 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
3. 7.69 µs ± 78.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

Answer (score 4):

I though it would be also good to give another example which you can both increase and decrease the number of counts

```
from collections import Counter

counter = Counter(["red", "yellow", "orange", "red", "orange"])
# to increase the count
counter.update({"yellow": 1})
# or
counter["yellow"] += 1

# to decrease
counter.update({"yellow": -1})
# or
counter["yellow"] -= 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
c.update({'foo': 1})
```

Comment: Isn't that the answer provided by @Psidom?

Comment: I didn't saw it when I answered.

Comment: Now that you've seen that your answer is virtually an exact copy of a previously provided answer and provides no new content, what do you think you should do with your answer?

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into the same problem recently. You can also put it in a tuple like this.

```py
c.update(('red',))
```

The previous answers haven't suggested this alternative, so I might as well post it here.

Comment: "First convert it to a list, tuple, etc."  This was suggested as an alternative, although I didn't bother giving an example.